# How to pass array in XHR.get request of Luci openwrt?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, lua, luci

I am trying to send array from javascript to XHR.get request in Luci Openwrt .

```
var myarray[] has some contents . for example : `myarray[] = {"1","2","3"}`
```

I need to pass this array to `XHR.get` requests as arguments . How can i pass this array ?

This is sample code :

```
XHR.get('<%=REQUEST_URI%>', {status: 2,value: myarray},
    function(x, info) {
        if (!info) {
            location.href=location.href;
        }
        else {
            console.log("success");
        }
    }
);
```

and in Lua code I am receiving this form data :

```
if luci.http.formvalue("status") == "2" then
    local DetailValue[] = luci.http.formvalue("value")
    local fileContent = {
        content = "sample1",
        find = "sample2"
    }
    luci.http.prepare_content("application/json")
    luci.http.write_json(fileContent)
    return
end
```

But I am getting errors. Is this correct way to send array via XHR.get ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: The first suggestion is to share the errors you are getting. *Always.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for one value

```
XHR.get('<%=url('admin/services/sample')%>',  { example : 'test' }, function(x) {
        <do whatever>
});

function parse_gateway()
    local example = luci.http.formvalue("example")
end
```

When I attempted to pass in two query parameters with the same key I got the the following

```
XHR.get('<%=url('admin/services/sample')%>',  { example : 'test', example : 'test1' }, function(x) {
        <do whatever>
});

function parse_gateway()
    local example = luci.http.formvalue("example")
end
```

This time example was `test1`

So in your case seems like you will have to have unique parameter keys.

```
XHR.get('<%=url('admin/services/sample')%>',  { one : '1', two : '2', three : '3' }, function(x) {
        <do whatever>
});

function parse_gateway()
    local one = luci.http.formvalue("one")
    local two = luci.http.formvalue("two")
    local three = luci.http.formvalue("three")
end
```